# How to find the $\cot2θ=\frac{A-C}{B}$

Tags: trigonometry

> $4x^2+y^2+4xy+x-2y = 0$

To find the angle of rotation of the axes of the above equation I need to solve.

$\cot2θ=\frac{A-C}{B}$

$A =$ the term with $x^2$, $C =$ the term with $y^2$, $B =$ the term with $xy$

$\cot2θ=\frac{4-1}{4}=3/4$

Comment: what is denoted by $$A,B,C$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner A = the term with $x^2$, C = the term with $xy$, B = the term with $y^2$

Comment: You know that $\cot(\pi/2) = 1/\tan(\pi/2) = 0 \implies 2\theta = \pi/2$.

Comment: @MathLover thanks, could you please show me how to solve this one ?  $\cot2θ=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Comment: @MathLover I did it based on what you first did, is it right ? $cot(π/6)=1/tan(π/6)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}⟹2θ=π/3⟹θ=π/6$

Comment: Beware: you have two errors : C is the coefficient of $y^2$ and $2B$ (not $B$) is the coefficient of $xy$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have these formula memorized (an neither should you, for that matter). And I derive this from first principles.

Start with:

$x = x'\cos\theta + y'\sin\theta\\
y = x'\sin\theta - y'\cos\theta$

$x^2 = x'^2\cos^2\theta + y'^2\sin^2\theta + 2x'y'\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
y^2= x'^2\sin^2\theta + y'^2\cos^2\theta - 2x'y'\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
xy = (y'^2-x'^2)\sin\theta\cos\theta + x'y'(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)$

When we substitue into the original equation, $4x^2 + y^2 + 4xy \cdots$  what we really care about is the $x'y'$.  Temporarily, we will ignore any first degree terms and any $x'^2, y'^2$ terms.

$8x'y'\sin\theta\cos\theta -2x'y'\sin\theta\cos\theta + 4x'y'(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)\\
(3\sin 2\theta + 4\cos 2\theta)x'y'$

We will choose $\theta$ such that the coefficient of this term equals $0.$

$3\sin 2\theta + 4\cos 2\theta = 0\\
5 (0.6\sin 2\theta + 0.8\cos 2\theta) = 0\\
\sin \arctan \frac 34\sin 2\theta + \cos\arctan \frac 34\cos 2\theta = 0\\
\cos (2\theta - \arctan \frac 34) = 0\\
$

$\theta = \frac {\pi}{4} + \frac 12\arctan \frac 34$

$\tan\theta = 2\\
\sin\theta  = \frac {2}{\sqrt 5}\\
\cos\theta  = \frac {1}{\sqrt 5}\\
$

Alternatively, if you know some linear algebra.

$4x^2 + y^2 + 4xy  = \begin{bmatrix} x&y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 4&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

$ \begin{bmatrix} x&y\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \frac {1}{\sqrt5}&\frac {2}{\sqrt 5}\\
-\frac {2}{\sqrt 5}&\frac {1}{\sqrt 5}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac {1}{\sqrt5}&-\frac {2}{\sqrt 5}\\
\frac {2}{\sqrt 5}&\frac {1}{\sqrt 5}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac {1}{\sqrt5}&-\frac {2}{\sqrt 5}\\
\frac {2}{\sqrt 5}&\frac {1}{\sqrt 5}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

But, if you don't skip that section.

Completing the substitution, I get.
$5y'^2 + \sqrt 5 x'  = 0$ or $\sqrt 5y'^2 + x'  = 0$

Looking at the work in the original post.

$\cot 2\theta = \frac {A-C}{B}$ where $A$ is the coefficient of the $x^2$ term B is the coefficient of the $xy$ term and C is the coefficient of the $y^2$ term.

$\cot 2\theta = \frac {4-1}{4} = \frac {3}{4}$

Comment: I didn't understand much what you did, I have 3 formulas memorized to solve this. My teacher also showed this method with linear algebra, although she hasn't taught it yet, but I didn't understand. I'll spend a time trying to understad what you did.

Comment: Linear Algebra is a very powerful tool for a variety of problems, but most people (unless they go into STEM) never learn it as there is to much groundwork to establish than there is time for in the high-school curriculum.